# vboxmanage works only with sudo

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

i cant list all vms without sudo:

```
vboxmanage list vms
```

Shows nothing, but when i try this:

```
sudo vboxmanage list vms
```

It shows all vms. I've installed virtualbox with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Is that normal behavior?

Comment: Probably not, especially if you created the VMs under your own user account (you didn't launch VirtualBox with `sudo`) and the VMs are in your `VirtualBox VMs` folder.

Comment: my VirtualBox VMs folder is under: /root/VirtualBox VMs

Comment: That's the problem. That folder is owned by `root` and you need `sudo` to see anything in the folder.

Comment: How can i install virtualbox as non-root user?

Comment: That's not the issue. The issue is that you likely used `sudo virtualbox` to launch VirtualBox, and so the VMs are in the `root`'s home folder. Also, just to check, what user are you logged in as?

Comment: yes, i've used sudo virtualbox because if i run just: virtualbox - when i close virtualbox it throws many errors in CLI. And i am logged as "alexander" (that's my username)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16532/discussion-between-saiarcot895-and-heihachi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sudo virtualbox` is used to launch VirtualBox, which would create the VMs in the `root`'s home directory, and so this would require `sudo` to read any VMs. The errors [here](http://i.snag.gy/M2Q9Z.jpg) are just warnings from Qt and can be safely ignored.